# Why i cant see source code from this dll

Tags: decompilation

// PE file does not contain any managed metadata.
[image]

Comment: If I understand the message correctly. then this means the DLL is not a .NET DLL and thus can not be decompiled using ILSpy. You need to use a tool like Ghidra or IDA (Pro) to decompile it, but be aware that decompiling non dot net DLLs is much harder, thus the decompiled code will much harder to read and some times even be wrong.